# how to replace &amp;#8364; into &#8364; with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to fix this forum where html entities are not displayed correctly.
since the owner is m.i.a. i'm trying to do this with an extension.

what i see on my screen:

```
euro:&#8364;
pound:&#163;
```

view of the html DOM with firebug

[image: bit of html-dom as seen with firebug]

my code:

```
GM_log('before text= '+text); 
text.replace( /amp;/gi, function( $0 ) {
    GM_log('$0= '+$0);
    fix="";
    return fix; 
});
GM_log(' after text= '+text);
```

which returns:

```
 before text= euro: &amp;#8364; <br>pound: &amp;#163;
 $0= amp;
 $0= amp;
 after text= euro: &amp;#8364; <br>pound: &amp;#163;
```

so my code seems to be working until the point it has to replace.

are those rectangles preventing it? did i do something wrong?

and if so how can i fix this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to assign the result of `replace`:

```
text = text.replace(...);
```